# Hot Linked Own Images

Tags: images

I have seemed to have an issue with Hot Linked images. Not someone else's, but my own. This page: https://www.iscd.org/event/minneapolis-mn-dxa-body-composition-analysis-course/ The image is shown with the Hot linked overlay. The actual image is in my own media directory and linked from there.

Copy of my .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Has anyone run across this issue before? 
Thank you

Comment: This is not overlay, your actual image has this hotlinked icon hardcoded, https://am.iscd.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/button_register-body-comp-course.png

Comment: Strange one. The thumbnail was altered. Thanks